# php array after parsing from excel to json

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

how to convert such an array to JSON ?  the array is obtained after parsing excel table , and some fields are empty ,

```
      0 => array:10 [▼
    0 => "number"
    1 => null
    2 => "274"
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => null
    8 => null
    9 => null
  ]



 1 => array:10 [▼
    0 => "step"
    1 => null
    2 => "4"
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => null
    8 => null
    9 => null
  ]

  19 => array:10 [▼
0 => "details"
1 => null
2 => null
3 => null
4 => null
5 => null
6 => null
7 => null
8 => null
9 => null
```

]

to become like this  : i tried to remove all null values but that made it worse and harder to deal with .

```
{"number":"274","step":"4" , "details": null }
```

Comment: What do you have so far and what is the exact problem with it?

Comment: Loop through the array, creating a new associative array whose keys are `$element[0]` and values are `$element[2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original array, all the keys are in element `0` and the values are in element `2`. You can combine them with:

```
$new_array = array_combine(array_column($array, 0), array_column($array, 2));
echo json_encode($new_array);
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/pk1Rkt)

Comment: nop , that wont work , it says that the both arrays should be equal

Comment: I don't see how the two arrays can be different lengths.

Comment: i think its because of the last array , having  a null value on 2

Comment: yea , you are right , the problem was from those two next arrays  : 

  32 => array:6 [▼
    0 => "closet"
    1 => null
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
  ]
  33 => []

what to do with them ?

Comment: You could use `array_filter()` to remove empty rows.